# Bind an enum to a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a basic enum for gender with value assignemnts 1, 2 for male and female. This code worked for me in previous mvc, but I am getting errors in asp.net core

any pointers as whats wrong ?
thanks

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Gender, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Accounts.i_EF.Accounts.Gender)).Cast<Accounts.i_EF.Accounts.Gender>().Select(c => SelectListItem { Text = c.ToString(), Value = c.ToString() } ))
```

Comment: if only we knew what error you are getting ...

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Its asp.net core 2,

Comment: @deepak sharma is One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

    The type or namespace name 'Gender' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

                        <select asp-for="Gender" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>()"></select>

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns and I get a red underline underneath selectlistItem, text c.ToString() and value c.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MVC6, there is one method `GetEnumSelectList`  which can be used to create the dropdown.

```
<select asp-for="Gender" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>()">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your previous code, try to change to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Gender, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)).Cast<Gender>().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ToString(), Value = c.ToString() } ))
```

> Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

For this, try to clean and rebuild your project. If not work, restart your VS.